# Unable to get IP address from a REST call to ELB in AWS, Instead i get a DNS name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

When making a REST call to AWS ELB the XML response obtained has DNS name but unable to fetch an IP address of the LoadBalancer.
But when i do a REST call for LoadBalancers in Azure i obtain an IP address associated with it.
Is it possible to get an IP address instead of DNS name in AWS?

Check the below response and you can see that we have

```
<DNSName>my-load-balancer-424835706.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com</DNSName>
```

```
<DescribeLoadBalancersResponse xmlns="http://elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/doc/2015-12-01/">
  <DescribeLoadBalancersResult>
    <LoadBalancers> 
      <member> 
        <LoadBalancerArn>arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:loadbalancer/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188</LoadBalancerArn> 
        <Scheme>internet-facing</Scheme> 
        <LoadBalancerName>my-load-balancer</LoadBalancerName> 
        <VpcId>vpc-3ac0fb5f</VpcId> 
        <CanonicalHostedZoneId>Z2P70J7EXAMPLE</CanonicalHostedZoneId> 
        <CreatedTime>2016-03-25T21:26:12.920Z</CreatedTime> 
        <AvailabilityZones> 
          <member> 
            <SubnetId>subnet-8360a9e7</SubnetId> 
            <ZoneName>us-west-2a</ZoneName> 
          </member> 
          <member> 
            <SubnetId>subnet-b7d581c0</SubnetId> 
            <ZoneName>us-west-2b</ZoneName> 
          </member> 
        </AvailabilityZones> 
        <SecurityGroups> 
          <member>sg-5943793c</member> 
        </SecurityGroups> 
        <DNSName>my-load-balancer-424835706.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com</DNSName>
        <State> 
          <Code>active</Code> 
        </State> 
        <Type>application</Type> 
      </member> 
    </LoadBalancers> 
  </DescribeLoadBalancersResult> 
  <ResponseMetadata> 
    <RequestId>6581c0ac-f39f-11e5-bb98-57195a6eb84a</RequestId> 
  </ResponseMetadata>
</DescribeLoadBalancersResponse>
```

I expect to fetch the IP address instead of DNS name and i have looked into all possible documentations. Want to know if its possible to fetch IP or want to know if AWS supports it or not.

Comment: Can you take the returned DNS name and use a DNS hostname resolver to get the ips? Note, in AWS a DNS look up on an ELB will return two ups.

Comment: why do you need the IP? Using the DNS name will be more fault tolerant.

Answer (score 0):

`AWS ELB` IP addresses keeps changing. You should instead use the DNS name provided to you.

You can get current IP, even by `dig`, but... there's no point, because it still can change - you don't know when, it depends, mainly on hardware (when ELB hosting machine breaks up - it sets up new and replace IP under DNS / scaling up/down ELB machines).